# duplicate visitor counter when refresh page

Tags: php

i have code to count number of visitor to my website and save it to file

but when any one make refresh page, counter is increase  .. 
i don't want duplicate count when any one refresh page
i need to know who visit my website really. i want exact number
and my code is

```
<?php 

// Open the file for reading 
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "r"); 

// Get the existing count 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

// Add 1 to the existing count 
$count = $count + 1; 

// Display the number of hits 
// If you don't want to display it, comment out this line 
echo "<p>Page views:" . $count . "</p>"; 

// Reopen the file and erase the contents 
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", "w"); 

// Write the new count to the file 
fwrite($fp, $count); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

please help me

Comment: Sorry to say, there is no "exact number". What exactly do you count as a "visitor"?

Comment: Ever heard of a cookie? Use one. Also, seriously, give up on the "exact count" thing. A significant portion of traffic for every site is bots, scrapers, hackers looking for vulnerabilities, and other non-visitor nonsense. Don't reinvent the wheel; just use something like Google Analytics or a basic stats package.

Comment: @Alexander i want count of who visit my site.without duplicate with refresh or visit page again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely, there's something else creating a page load, for example when the browser requests the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). Check the server access logs. If you're on a Unix system, they're generally located in `/var/logs/apache2/access.log`.

Comment: i am use linux server - fedora- where can i get access.log

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and misses the point entirely. The script makes no distinction between visits, as it doesn't use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider one individual as one visitor, then you will have to have authentication mechanism. That way you can keep track counting 'how many email id's have been registred at your site' or 'how many usernames have been registred at your site'.

If you want to keep track of daily visitors, then you will have to track them through the ip addresses, where one person from one ip address is one visitor. Apart from this, you can use analytics tools available online such as google analytics etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the moment each request your server receive is counted as one visitor. It is for real one "page view".

Identify which request are coming from the same visitors is not an easy task to do. Request are something the computer understand, a "visitor" is a human concept.

How can you identify visitor ?

- if your visitor are all logged in (no anonymous traffic) then it will be easy to check how many people are visiting
- you can consider all request coming from the same IP address are coming from the same person (that is not true but not far from truth)
- you can set a cookie on visitor first request so you identify further request as coming from the same visitor. You will likely be underestimating your stats if two visitors use the same computer, they will be counted only once.
- you can use and trust external tools to make your stats, like Google Analytics